# What are the ways to manage Android resource ids without using R.java?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android  . . .Till now i was thinking that all the resource's ids are in android app are managed and mapped using R.java file. But i got an application in market to work on,in which i did not found `R.java/R.class` file in it, after decompiling it using `dex2jar` utility
my issue is that till now my work was dependant on R.java/ R.class file , I was accessing all ids in an app using this file and reflection concept. But since this app does not contain R.class file my work is stuckked for now.

Interesting thing for me is that, when i create dex file from this jar and replace it in app and sign app using one_click_signer ,the app works fine on mobile.

So ,

1. i want to know how they could have managed ids without R.java?
2. Is it possible to have an application without R.java, or i may have
   made mistake while decompiling app?
3. how can i find ids in the application?

Comment: **"...after decompiling it using dex2jar utility..."** So you're reverse-engineering other peoples apps?

Comment: yes . . i am reverse engineering the app and making changes in them . .

Answer (score 1):

They used R but it was optimized away.

Let's say the app had this code:

```
public class R {
    public static class id {
        public static final int something = 123456;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public void doSomething() {
        doSomethingWith(R.id.something);
    }
}
```

When compiling Java, the compiler "inlines" static final fields - replacing the field access with the value, since the compiler already knows the value. That means the compiler translates the code to this:

```
public class R {
    public static class id {
        public static final int something = 123456;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public void doSomething() {
        doSomethingWith(123456);
    }
}
```

If the application is optimized/obfuscated with Proguard - which is common with Android applications - then Proguard would then detect that the class "R" is not used and delete it, resulting in this:

```
public class Main {
    public void doSomething() {
        doSomethingWith(123456);
    }
}
```